# JEST でのテスト実行時のみ、 TypeError:xxx is not a function エラーが発生する

Tags: typescript, ethereum, jestjs

#### 概要

Typescript で書いているコードにて、
通常実行する分には問題ないが、Jestでテストを実行する際に
外部モジュール内部で「TypeError: xxx is not a function」が発生する。
エラーを解除しJESTでの試験を動作させたい

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

エラーメッセージ

```
TypeError: secp256k1.publicKeyCreate is not a function
 at Object.publickeyCreate( xxxxxxx/node_modules/xxxxx/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist/secp256k1-adapter.js:114:32)
         以下省略
```

#### 試したこと

Jset.config.js に
　　transformIgnorePatterns:['/node_modules/(?!ethreum-cryptography)/']
moduleDirectories:['node_modules','bower_components','src')
を追加